# Scrape tables into dataframe with BeautifulSoup

Tags: pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the data from the coins catalog.

There is [one of the pages](http://www.gcoins.net/en/catalog/view/45518). I need to scrape [this data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zqhW.png) into Dataframe

So far I have this code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

source = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.gcoins.net/en/catalog/view/45518').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'subs noBorders evenRows'})
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text for tr in td]
    print(row)                    # I need to save this data instead of printing it
```

It produces following output:

```
[]
['', '', '1882', '', '108,000', 'UNC', '—']
[' ', '', '1883', '', '786,000', 'UNC', '~ $3.99']
[' ', " \n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t$('subGraph55337').on('click', function(event) {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tLightview.show({\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\thref : '/en/catalog/ajax/subgraph?id=55337',\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\trel : 'ajax',\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\toptions : {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tautosize : true,\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\ttopclose : true,\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tajax : {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tevalScripts : true\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t} \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t});\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tevent.stop();\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\treturn false;\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t});\n\t\t\t\t\t\t", '1884', '', '4,604,000', 'UNC', '~ $2.08–$4.47']
[' ', '', '1885', '', '1,314,000', 'UNC', '~ $3.20']
['', '', '1886', '', '444,000', 'UNC', '—']
[' ', '', '1888', '', '413,000', 'UNC', '~ $2.88']
[' ', '', '1889', '', '568,000', 'UNC', '~ $2.56']
[' ', " \n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t$('subGraph55342').on('click', function(event) {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tLightview.show({\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\thref : '/en/catalog/ajax/subgraph?id=55342',\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\trel : 'ajax',\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\toptions : {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tautosize : true,\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\ttopclose : true,\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tajax : {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tevalScripts : true\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t} \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t});\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tevent.stop();\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\treturn false;\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t});\n\t\t\t\t\t\t", '1890', '', '2,137,000', 'UNC', '~ $1.28–$4.79']
['', '', '1891', '', '605,000', 'UNC', '—']
[' ', '', '1892', '', '205,000', 'UNC', '~ $4.47']
[' ', '', '1893', '', '754,000', 'UNC', '~ $4.79']
[' ', '', '1894', '', '532,000', 'UNC', '~ $3.20']
[' ', '', '1895', '', '423,000', 'UNC', '~ $2.40']
['', '', '1896', '', '174,000', 'UNC', '—']
```

But when I'm trying to save it to Dataframe and export to excel it contains just the last value:

```
         0
0         
1         
2     1896
3         
4  174,000
5      UNC
6        —
```

Comment: How did you do to `save it to Dataframe` ?

Comment: Hi, phi. Good catch. I didn't mention it. I just added 2 lines more: df = pd.DataFrame(row) and df.to_excel('coins.xlsx'). The data in the for loop wa overwriting.

Comment: You can also use ```df['col'].str.strip('\n')``` to delete \n

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this

```
l = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text for tr in td]
    l.append(row)
pd.DataFrame(l, columns=["A", "B", ...])
```

Answer (score 110):

Pandas already has a built-in method to convert the table on the web to a dataframe:

```
table = soup.find_all('table')
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No point in using `BeautifulSoup` for this use case.

Comment: This seems right but has inconsistent behaviour loosing vast amounts of table rows.

Answer (score 18):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'subs noBorders evenRows'})
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

res = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in td if tr.text.strip()]
    if row:
        res.append(row)


df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=["Year", "Mintage", "Quality", "Price"])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   Year  Mintage Quality    Price
0  1882  108,000     UNC        —
1  1883  786,000     UNC  ~ $4.03
```

Comment: Hi, Rakesh. Thanks for your answer. It works for me as well. I just chose the phi's answer because it boosted my work yesterday :) Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Just a head's up... This part of Rakesh's code means that only HTML rows containing text will be included in the dataframe, as the rows don't get appended if row is an empty list:

```
if row:
    res.append(row)
```

Problematic in my use case, where I wanted to compare row indexing for the HTML and dataframe tables later on. I just needed to change it to:

```
res.append(row)
```

Also, if a cell in the row is empty, it doesn't get included. This then messes up the columns. So I changed

```
row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in td if tr.text.strip()]
```

to

```
row = [d.text.strip() for d in td]
```

But, otherwise, it's working for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

No need for Beautifulsoup at all. If you just want to extract html tables into DataFrames just use

```
dfs = pd.read_html(url)
```

With url being the actual website url (i.e. 'http://www.gcoins.net/en/catalog/view/45518').

The pandas function will parse the page automatically and return a list of dataframe objects created from the tables in the HTML code.

Answer (score 2):

Since Pandas has a built-in parser that has a method to convert the table on the web to a dataframe, you can also use the following prettify() method on a beautifulsoup table element as an input to the pandas read_html method to get the dataframe/dataframes from the element:

```
table_elem = soup.find('table')
df = pd.read_html(table_elem.prettify())[0]
```