# Webscraping into Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Beautiful Soup and trying to scrape https://10times.com/losangeles-us/technology/conferences and extract event data and their associated links.

I've managed to scrape the event data and their links, but I'm struggling with getting the proper event to line up with the proper event link when combining into a dataframe. I've tried dropping the null results, however, I cannot figure it out.

Here's my code which is extracting the data

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://10times.com/losangeles-us/technology/conferences').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')

table = soup.find('tbody')

table_rows = table.find_all('tr')#find table rows (tr)


arr=[]
for tr in table_rows:   
    td = tr.find_all('td')  #find all the table data
    row = [tr.text for tr in td]
    arr.append(row) #This line > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633050/scrape-tables-into-dataframe-with-beautifulsoup    
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['Date', 'Event Name', 'Venue', 'Description', 'Type', 'Unnamed:'])
df.columns = ['Date', 'Event Name', 'Venue', 'Description', 'Type', 'Interested/Following Count'] 
df.dropna()
df
```

Here's my code extracting the links

```
arr2 = []
#finds <h2's>
h2s = soup.find_all('h2')
for h2 in h2s:
    links = h2.a['href']
    arr2.append(links)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(arr2)
df2.columns = ['Links'] 
df2.dropna()
```

Here are my 2 attempts at combining the event data + links into one dataframe, however, the links aren't matching up to the correct event.

```
from pandas import *

df3 = pd.concat([df,df2],sort=False, axis=1)
df3
#df3.to_html('test1.html')
```

Trying to drop None

```
df.dropna()
df3 = pd.concat([df,df2], sort=False, axis=1)
df3 = df3.replace(to_replace='None', value=np.nan).dropna()
df3
```

Comment: Your df have 44 rows while your links Series have 39 rows. The function pd.concat() will just append the links as a column and fill the latested missing values with NaN.

Comment: You can avoid using find_all(), and learn about css selector. The method select() will give you more power to do what you want. After select the set of Tags you want using css selector, getting "href" will be easier.

Comment: Don't use `import *`, it's generally bad practice. What is the point of doing `df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['Date', 'Event Name', 'Venue', 'Description', 'Type', 'Unnamed:']);
df.columns = ['Date', 'Event Name', 'Venue', 'Description', 'Type', 'Interested/Following Count']` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an check if there is information in "row" at the first block of code.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://10times.com/losangeles-us/technology/conferences').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')

table = soup.find('tbody')

table_rows = table.find_all('tr')#find table rows (tr)


arr=[]
for tr in table_rows:   
    td = tr.find_all('td')  #find all the table data
    row = [tr.text for tr in td]
    if len(row) > 1:
        arr.append(row) #This line > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633050/scrape-tables-into-dataframe-with-beautifulsoup    
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['Date', 'Event Name', 'Venue', 'Description', 'Type', 'Unnamed:'])
df.columns = ['Date', 'Event Name', 'Venue', 'Description', 'Type', 'Interested/Following Count']
df
```

This seems to work.

Comment: Duhh, this is an obvious solution I didn't think of! Thank you!