# Beautiful soup extracting rows and data

Tags: pandas, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful soup to pull some data from a internal site. The code provided on the links work for 4 columns of my data. There is one more data tagged as th.How can i get th on the same row with all tds.
[Scrape tables into dataframe with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633050/scrape-tables-into-dataframe-with-beautifulsoup)

```
Manager ID   Defect Count    Transactions     DPMO
bedfli          155            2215         898
elojr           26             745          480
torse           0              16            0
jogsn           115            1767         6783

res = []
for tr in rows:
td = tr.find_all('td')
row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in td if tr.text.strip()]
if row:
    res.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(res,columns = ['Manager ID','Defect Count','Transactions','DPMO'])
print(df)

<tr role = 'row'>
<td>bedfli</td>
<th>Receive</th>
<td>155</td>
<td>2215</td>
<td>898</td>
```

I want th(receive) on my dataframe with 5 columns including receive so the final output looks like

```
Manager ID Process Defect Count Transaction DPMO
bedfli       Receive   155          2215       898
```

Comment: use [pandas.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html)

Answer (score 0):

Solutions using library SimplifiedDoc.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<table>
<tr>
<td>Manager ID</td>
<th>Process</th>
<td>Defect Count</td>
<td>Transaction</td>
<td>DPMO</td>
</tr>
<tr role = 'row'>
<td>bedfli</td>
<th>Receive</th>
<td>155</td>
<td>2215</td>
<td>898</td>
</tr>
</table>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
# First way
table = doc.getTable(body='table')
# Second way
table = doc.selects('table>tr').children.text
# Third way
table = doc.selects('table>tr').selects('td|th').text
print (table)
```

Result:

```
[['Manager ID', 'Process', 'Defect Count', 'Transaction', 'DPMO'], ['bedfli', 'Receive', '155', '2215', '898']]
```