# Scraping a specific table from a web page using python3 (web page has multiple tables)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extra the data from a specific table on a web page. There are multiple tables on the page so I am trying to use the table ID to extract only the required table.

url: https://basketball.realgm.com/player/Luke-Nelson/Summary/50483

The code I have so far is the following.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import ssl


# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

#URL input
url = 'https://basketball.realgm.com/player/Luke-Nelson/Summary/50483'
html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

table = soup.find('table', id='table-1696')
print(table)
```

I have assumed the print statement would print the HTML from the table (has previously worked just on one table) but when I run the programme it has the following output:

[Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFWbK.png)

Ultimately I'm aiming to re-create the table in python and export to excel, but can't get over this first hurdle!

Here is the HTML for the table within the webpage

```html
<table class="tablesaw compact tablesaw-swipe tablesaw-sortable" data-tablesaw-mode="swipe" data-tablesaw-mode-switch="" data-tablesaw-mode-exclude="columntoggle" data-tablesaw-sortable="" data-tablesaw-sortable-switch="" id="table-1696" style="">
<thead><tr class="per_game per_48 per_40 per_36 per_minute minute_per total">
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" data-tablesaw-priority="persist" data-tablesaw-sortable-default-col="" class="tablesaw-cell-persist tablesaw-sortable-head tablesaw-sortable-ascending"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">Season</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">Team</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">League</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">GP</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">GS</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">MIN</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">FGM</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">FGA</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">FG%</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">3PM</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">3PA</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">3P%</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">FTM</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">FTA</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">FT%</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">OFF</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">DEF</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">TRB</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">AST</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">STL</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head tablesaw-cell-hidden"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">BLK</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head tablesaw-cell-hidden"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">PF</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head tablesaw-cell-hidden"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">TOV</button></th>
<th data-tablesaw-sortable-col="" class="tablesaw-sortable-head tablesaw-cell-hidden"><button class="tablesaw-sortable-btn">PTS</button></th>
</tr></thead><tbody><tr class="per_game">
<td class="tablesaw-cell-persist">2012-13</td>
<td id="teamLineinternational_reg_Per_Game_1"><a href="/international/league/47/adidas-Next-Generation-Tournament/team/1304/Team-England-U18-Men">Team England U18 Men</a></td>
<td><a href="/international/league/47/adidas-Next-Generation-Tournament">ANGT</a></td>
<td>3</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>33.3</td>
<td>6.00</td>
<td>16.33</td>
<td>.367</td>
<td>1.33</td>
<td>4.33</td>
<td>.308</td>
<td>2.33</td>
<td>2.67</td>
<td>.875</td>
<td>0.00</td>
<td>3.33</td>
<td>3.33</td>
<td>5.67</td>
<td>2.00</td>
<td class="tablesaw-cell-hidden">0.33</td>
<td class="tablesaw-cell-hidden">3.00</td>
<td class="tablesaw-cell-hidden">3.67</td>
<td class="tablesaw-cell-hidden">15.67</td>
</tr>
<tr class="per_game">
<td class="tablesaw-cell-persist">2017-18</td>
<td id="teamLineinternational_reg_Per_Game_2"><a href="/international/league/4/Spanish-ACB/team/212/Coosur-Real-Betis">Coosur Real Betis</a></td>
<td><a href="/international/league/4/Spanish-ACB">ACB</a></td>
<td>34</td>
<td>28</td>
<td>23.2</td>
<td>2.97</td>
<td>6.74</td>
<td>.441</td>
<td>1.47</td>
<td>3.59</td>
<td>.410</td>
<td>0.79</td>
<td>1.03</td>
<td>.771</td>
<td>0.24</td>
<td>1.91</td>
<td>2.15</td>
<td>1.68</td>
<td>1.06</td>
<td class="tablesaw-cell-hidden">0.03</td>
<td class="tablesaw-cell-hidden">3.00</td>
<td class="tablesaw-cell-hidden">1.82</td>
<td class="tablesaw-cell-hidden">8.21</td>
</tr>
<tr class="per_game">
<td class="tablesaw-cell-persist">2019-20 *</td>
<td id="teamLineinternational_reg_Per_Game_3">All Teams</td>
<td>All Leagues</td>
<td>17</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>16.7</td>
<td>2.82</td>
<td>7.29</td>
<td>.387</td>
<td>1.35</td>
<td>3.88</td>
<td>.348</td>
<td>1.35</td>
<td>1.59</td>
<td>.852</td>
<td>0.24</td>
<td>0.94</td>
<td>1.18</td>
<td>2.47</td>
<td>0.71</td>
<td class="tablesaw-cell-hidden">0.18</td>
<td class="tablesaw-cell-hidden">2.24</td>
<td class="tablesaw-cell-hidden">1.59</td>
<td class="tablesaw-cell-hidden">8.35</td>
</tr>
<tr class="per_game multiple-teams-highlight">
<td class="tablesaw-cell-persist">2019-20 *</td>
<td id="teamLineinternational_reg_Per_Game_4"><a href="/international/league/4/Spanish-ACB/team/473/ICL-Manresa">ICL Manresa</a></td>
<td><a href="/international/league/4/Spanish-ACB">ACB</a></td>
<td>9</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>13.6</td>
<td>1.78</td>
<td>5.56</td>
<td>.320</td>
<td>0.56</td>
<td>2.89</td>
<td>.192</td>
<td>1.56</td>
<td>1.67</td>
<td>.933</td>
<td>0.33</td>
<td>0.78</td>
<td>1.11</td>
<td>1.89</td>
<td>0.22</td>
<td class="tablesaw-cell-hidden">0.00</td>
<td class="tablesaw-cell-hidden">1.89</td>
<td class="tablesaw-cell-hidden">1.56</td>
<td class="tablesaw-cell-hidden">5.67</td>
</tr>
<tr class="per_game multiple-teams-highlight">
<td class="tablesaw-cell-persist">2019-20 *</td>
<td id="teamLineinternational_reg_Per_Game_5"><a href="/international/league/106/Basketball-Champions-League-Europe/team/473/ICL-Manresa">ICL Manresa</a></td>
<td><a href="/international/league/106/Basketball-Champions-League-Europe">BCL-Eu</a></td>
<td>8</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>20.3</td>
<td>4.00</td>
<td>9.25</td>
<td>.432</td>
<td>2.25</td>
<td>5.00</td>
<td>.450</td>
<td>1.12</td>
<td>1.50</td>
<td>.750</td>
<td>0.12</td>
<td>1.12</td>
<td>1.25</td>
<td>3.12</td>
<td>1.25</td>
<td class="tablesaw-cell-hidden">0.38</td>
<td class="tablesaw-cell-hidden">2.62</td>
<td class="tablesaw-cell-hidden">1.62</td>
<td class="tablesaw-cell-hidden">11.38</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

Thank you for taking the time to read my question and hopefully I have explained it fully, I am very new to coding/programming (started a couple of weeks ago) so please keep this in mind with any responses. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Adam, if you do simple print(soup) first, you'll notice that table id's are not in the soup to begin with. I have also noticed that table id's change every time you refresh the page so extracting by table id's might not be suitable here. I'm also not sure why soup is not ingesting table ids. You could try another approach such as finding a '<div>' with text that you want and then find the next <table> tag immediately afterwards.

Comment: thank you for your reply. The finding the table header has solved this, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pandas to get the table tag and use the id attribute to select the one you want:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://basketball.realgm.com/player/Luke-Nelson/Summary/50483'
df = pd.read_html(url, attrs={'id':'table-1696'})[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(url) # df -> list of tables

print(len(df)) # 29
```

And you can choose table what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The table id's are being assigned dynamically so I would suggest an alternative way to get to your table. Let's say you want to get the table for NBA Summer League Stats - Totals, try:

```
table_heading = 'NBA Summer League Stats - Totals'
table = soup.find(string=re.compile(table_heading))
          .find_parent()
          .find_next_sibling()
print(table)
```

You can change the `table_heading` for other headings on the table. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. It works and I now have individual table HTML. The 'select table heading' will help further down the line for my final programme so win win! I have tried to convert the 'table' variable using `df = pd.read_html(table)` but it is coming back with a long error message `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` Do I need to import another library? Sorry I appreciate it is probably something simple but can't find the answer, thank you

Comment: Hi Adam, glad it solved your issue. In order to convert the table into a dataframe, I would suggest reviewing this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633050/scrape-tables-into-dataframe-with-beautifulsoup/50633450 or perhaps asking another question as that's just the way StackOverflow works with specific questions. Hope it helps and can you accept this answer as solution.

Comment: Thank you very much