# how to correctly fetch dataframe from url in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to automate data fetching from USDA website, where I am specifically interested in few categories for data selection. To do so, I tried the following:

```
import io
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.marketnews.usda.gov/mnp/ls-report-retail?&repType=summary&portal=ls&category=Retail&species=BEEF&startIndex=1'

query_list = {"Report Type":"item","species":"BEEF","portal":"ls","category":"Retail", "Regions":"National", "Grades":"ALL", "Cut": "All", "Dates_from":"2019-03-01", "Dates_to":"2021-02-01"}
req = requests.get(url, params=query_list)
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(req.text), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
df.to_csv("usda_report.csv")
```

but I couldn't get the expected dataframe that I want, here is the output that after I tried to run above attempt:

> ParserError: Expected 1 fields in line 117, saw 2. Error could
> possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is
> used.

**desired output**

I need to pass these queries to do correct data selection: `Category = "Retail";  Report Type = "Item"; Species = "Beef"; Region(s) = "National"; Dates_from = "2019-03-01"; Dates_to = "2021-02-15"`.

ideally, I want to pass those queries and want to get the following dataframe (head of dataframe):

[image]

**update**

in my desired outputs, I need those columns: `Date`, `Region`, `Grade`, `Cut`, `Retail Items`, `Outlets` or `number of stores`, `Weighted Avg`

from the above attempt, I couldn't get the output dataframe like this. How should I fetch data correctly? Can anyone suggest possible of doing this right in pandas? any idea?

Comment: As an aside, an alternative method is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50633450/7287543) with BeautifulSoup scraping and a simple for-loop.

Comment: You can only use pandas.read_csv if the input is a csv. You can't parse arbitrary html pages like this.

Comment: @Yehuda how can we do this using `BeautifulSoup scraping` instead? Do you have the possible approach to get my expected output? any thoughts?

Comment: @HåkenLid query_list is not working at all for data selection, I don't why. How can we get desired output as I showed above? any idea?

Comment: @Hamilton Check the link I provided. The first half of the code from the question (through `table_rows = table.find_all('tr')`) should get you the data; then add the code from the linked answer to  finish it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the query parameter `format=text` to get the data in csv format from this web site.

```
url = 'https://www.marketnews.usda.gov/mnp/ls-report-retail'
query_list = {
    "format":"text", 
    "repType":"item",
    "species":"BEEF",
    "portal":"ls",
    "region":"NATIONAL",
    "cut":"0",
    "repDate":"03/01/2019", 
    "endDate":"02/01/2021",
}
req = requests.get(url, params=query_list)
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(req.text), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
```

You might have to modify the query parameters further. You can use the web site with your browser and change the filters you want. Then you can convert the current query parameters in the url to json with this command in the javascript terminal.

```
JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(location.search)), null, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. If I use above attempt, I can't get desired output like I showed above. Any possible updates? Is that doable to get my desired output dataframe? Thanks!

Comment: You still get the same error? Did you also change the last line? In your question you are using `req` in one line and `r` in the next.

Comment: yep, now error is gone but not getting desired output and some of the queries are not working for data selection. Any possible updates to get desired output? Thanks

Comment: Seems like some of your query parameters were invalid. I can change the ones I'm able to guess.

Comment: I've changed some of the incorrect parameters in `query_list`. There might be others. You should use the web site and change the filters to what you want. Then press submit and check what the current query parameters are. You can open the javascript console and do this:  `JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(location.search)), null,2)`

Comment: `"repDate":"2019/03/01", "endDate":"2021/02/01"` are still not working. Why? Any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229073/discussion-between-hamilton-and-haken-lid).

Comment: I've updated the dates in my answer. It's MM/DD/YYYY and works as expected. I think you have to figure out the rest by yourself. :)