# Beautiful Soup find_all not finding them all

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape covid data from an online table (can be found by visiting [this site](https://www.mohfw.gov.in/), and clicking the pink "State Data" button on the far-right end of the sub-header). I used a combination of selenium (click the button, then store the source html using
`driver.page_source()`) and BeautifulSoup to parse through the page's html. On my first run, I was able successfully locate the table, loop through the table's rows, and store the rows in a pandas.DataFrame no problem ([using this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633050/scrape-tables-into-dataframe-with-beautifulsoup)). However when attempting it again later on, I'm not able to locate all the table's rows like I did the first time.

Here's my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:/Work/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.mohfw.gov.in/')

# click state data
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="site-dashboard"]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/ul/li/a[2]/img').click()
page_html = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

##
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "lxml")
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'statetable table table-striped'})
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

# append each row to a list
l = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text for tr in td]
    l.append(row)

# get rid of the rows that have less than 7 entries 
#  (each entry represents a column. The last row has 7 because it's a total and wasn't given a row ID)
l2 = [i for i in l if len(i)>=7]

for count, element in enumerate(l2):
    if len(element) == 7:
        element.insert(0, count+1)

# Convert to DataFrame
pd.DataFrame(l2, columns=["S. No.", 
                          "Name of State / UT", 
                          "Total Active Cases", 
                          "Change in Total Active Cases Since Yesterday", 
                          "Cumulative Cured/Discharged/Migrated", 
                          "Change in Cumulative Cured/Discharged/Migrated Since Yesterday", 
                          "Cumulative Deaths", 
                          "Change in Cumulative Deaths Since Yesterday"]).replace(r'\xa0 ', pd.NA, regex=True)
```

From what I read online, there may be broken HTML on the page. When I threw the output of the `table` variable into sublime text and set the syntax to HTML, I noticed that the section of HTML I needed to parse was greyed out (vs. the rest of the colorful text at the top, only of which was being returned by `find_all()`). Something is telling me that the `<!--<tbody>` tag is what's greying out the section I need to parse, but my attempts at removing it have been unsuccessful. I know very little about HTML so maybe a more experienced eye could quickly deduce what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see is loaded from external URL via Json. You can use this example to load it:

```
import json
import requests


url = "https://www.mohfw.gov.in/data/datanew.json"
data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for d in data:
    print(
        "{:<50} {:<10} {}".format(
            d["state_name"], d["new_active"], d["new_cured"]
        )
    )
```

Prints:

```
Andaman and Nicobar Islands                        232        5879
Andhra Pradesh                                     159597     1016142
Arunachal Pradesh                                  1632       17501
Assam                                              29407      237088
Bihar                                              110431     410484
Chandigarh                                         8170       37288
Chhattisgarh                                       124459     653542
Dadra and Nagar Haveli and Daman and Diu           1606       6564
Delhi                                              90419      1124771
Goa                                                26731      72799
Gujarat                                            148297     464396
Haryana                                            108830     429950
Himachal Pradesh                                   23572      85713
Jammu and Kashmir                                  37302      152109
Jharkhand                                          59707      194433
Karnataka                                          464383     1210013
Kerala                                             357215     1339257
Ladakh                                             1374       13035
Lakshadweep                                        1165       2078
Madhya Pradesh                                     86639      520024
Maharashtra                                        644068     4107092
Manipur                                            2391       30141
Meghalaya                                          2019       15810
Mizoram                                            1609       5168
Nagaland                                           1798       12801
Odisha                                             67437      410227
Puducherry                                         10849      51584
Punjab                                             61935      327976
Rajasthan                                          197045     466310
Sikkim                                             1930       6617
Tamil Nadu                                         125230     1109450
Telangana                                          77704      389491
Tripura                                            1905       33929
Uttarakhand                                        56627      144409
Uttar Pradesh                                      272568     1081817
West Bengal                                        120946     765843
                                                   3487229    16951731
```

Comment: Whoa. How did you know to find that url?

Comment: @Yacob I searched HTML source for the information but there isn't any. So the page must load the data from somewhere. In Firefox Developer Tools -> Network tab, there are all requests the page is doing.