# How do I get the output as a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

How do I get the output as a dataframe? I can't seem to find out what type the output is.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.bvb.de/Spiele/Alle-Spiele"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

table = soup.select("table.statistics")

for row in soup.select("tr:has(td)"):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ") for td in row.select("td")]
    if len(tds) > 2:
        team1, team2 = tds[1], tds[2]
        date = tds[0]
        opponent1 = tds[1]
        opponent2 = tds[2]
        score = tds[3]
        print(score)
```

Comment: *"..output as a dataframe"*. `import pandas as pd; df = pd.read_html(url)[0]` ?

Comment: Please, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633050/scrape-tables-into-dataframe-with-beautifulsoup